# function takes a list of 2-Tuples and a number

Tags: haskell

So.. I am trying to build a program that takes a list of 2-tuples and a number and check if the number equal one of the elements of the tuple, if it equal the first element then it return the last one and if it equal the last one it return the first one.

**
for example **[(5,4), (9,3) ,(4,2)] 4** 
 it returns [5,2]
**

Here is what I am thinking :

```
boomBangs :: (a, a) -> a -> [a]
boomBangs tt t = if snd tt == t then [fst tt] 
else if fst tt == t then [snd tt] else []
```

so the function takes a Tuple and a number, it check if the first element equal to the number if so it return the second element as a list if not it check if the second element equal the number if so it return the first element as list.

now I tried to code the main function as I described above,

```
vector :: [(a,a)] -> a -> [a]
vector xs v = [boomBangs tt | tt <- xs]
```

I tied with function map but also not working

```
vector :: [(a, a)] -> a -> [a]
vector xs = map boomBangs
```

Comment: This is a simple to implement functionality but it makes me wonder, what is it good for as it makes you to loose the `fst` and `snd` relationship of a tuple. You might not need a tuple to start with.

Comment: you are right I have change it , but still have problem with the the vector function I tried to use the map function but does not work to , vector xs = map boomBangs

Comment: You forgot to use the argument `v` in the function `vector`.

Comment: If you add `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}` to the top of the file, the compiler will warn about similar issues.

Comment: Also, please include the error message you get in the question next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to compile it? The compiler gives useful errors, you should read them and also include them in your questions in the future.

You're very close to a working answer, but you're missing a few small things.

Your `boomBangs` function is fine (but you'll need an `Eq a` constraint as the compiler will tell you), let's look at your `vector` implementations:

```
vector :: Eq a => [(a,a)] -> a -> [a]
vector xs v = [boomBangs tt | tt <- xs]
```

Your `boomBangs` function takes TWO arguments, but you're only passing one here, you're not using your `v` function at all. We need to pass `v` into the function:

```
vector :: Eq a => [(a,a)] -> a -> [a]
vector xs v = [boomBangs tt v | tt <- xs]
```

This is closer, but the compiler tells us more:

```
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
```

This is saying that it's expecting an `a`, but got an `[a]` instead. Our `boomBangs` function returns a list, and the list comprehension embeds all the results in a list, so our expression is actually of type `[[a]]` when all is said and done. We need to flatten it out. There's a function for that: `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]`

```
vector :: Eq a => [(a,a)] -> a -> [a]
vector xs v = concat [boomBangs tt v | tt <- xs]
```

This compiles and should work as you expect.

Your map version is also close, but you're again forgetting to apply all your arguments, you've only bound one of them (which you don't ever use!) and the other argument is being passed via point-free style (try not to mix the two styles).

Here's how we can fix it up:

```
vector' :: Eq a => [(a, a)] -> a -> [a]
vector' xs v = concat (map (flip boomBangs v) xs)
```

The flip is a little annoying, we can fix that by flipping the arguments to our original `boomBangs` function:

```
boomBangs :: Eq a =>  a -> (a, a) -> [a]
```

This allows us to write:

```
vector' :: Eq a => [(a, a)] -> a -> [a]
vector' xs v = concat (map (boomBangs v) xs)
```

If you prefer to simplify to point-free, we can flip the args to this function too:

```
vector' :: Eq a => a -> [(a, a)] -> [a]
vector' v = concat . (map (boomBangs v))
```

And we can use `concatMap` which combines concat and map into one function:

```
vector' :: Eq a => a -> [(a, a)] -> [a]
vector' v = concatMap (boomBangs v)
```

Cheers!